# When I try to play a video in ionic with react this error occurs 'cordova_not_available'

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my code. I have tried this code in ionic with react hooks.
I have already installed the video player plugin.
I have a problem. When I try to play a video in ionic with react this error occurs: `cordova_not_available`

```
import React from 'react';
import { VideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/video-player/ngx';

import { IonContent, IonList, IonListHeader, IonItem, IonLabel, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonImg, IonThumbnail, IonHeader } from '@ionic/react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Tab1.css';

const items = [{ src: 'images/download.jpg', text: 'Video 1' }, { src: 'images/download.jpg', text: 'Vidoe 2' }];

class Tab1 {
    const playVideo = ()=> {
        // alert(videoPlayer);
        VideoPlayer.play('file:///videos/videoplayback.mp4').then(() => {
            console.log('video completed');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    return (
        <IonContent>
            <IonHeader translucent>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>List</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            {/*-- List of Text Items --*/}
            <IonList>
                <IonListHeader>
                    Recent Videos
                </IonListHeader>
                {items.map((image, i) => (
                    <IonItem key={i}>
                        <IonThumbnail slot="start">
                            <IonImg onClick={playVideo} src={image.src} />
                        </IonThumbnail>
                        <IonLabel>{image.text}</IonLabel>
                    </IonItem>
                ))}
            </IonList>
        </IonContent>
    );
};

export default Tab1;
```

Comment: did you checked https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-cordova-not-available/110156

Comment: Wither you need to remove the build and rebuild again, or you added npm for videoplayer but didn't add the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you are testing in a browser environment. While [Cordova does support the browser](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/04/cordova-browser-6.0.0.html) as a platform, many plugins are only available on native devices. To continue with your video player plugin, you'll need to either test on an actual device or in a simulator/emulator.

It looks like there is a React Video Player component [available from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) that may suit your needs for running video in the browser.

Good luck!

Comment: @Rajendra Glad that worked! Do you mind accepting this as the answer so it gets marked as completed?